# Transposing few attributes in rows to columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, window-functions

I have an Order table that has the records as below:

```
UPDATE_DATE             ORDER_ID    FIELD_NAME      FIELD_VALUE
17-07-20                300009086   Order Stage     Shipped  
15-07-20                300009086   Order Stage     Provisioned
14-07-20                300009086   Order Stage     Order Created
14-07-20                300009086   Customer Name   XYZ Corp
```

So as can be seen, for a single order (300009086) we have multiple records in the table, with each record corresponding to each particular attribute of the order. Also as can be seen, when a particular attribute changes (e.g., Order Stage in the above sample data), we get an additional record created in the table.

Now, I have a target table that looks like the one given below and it contains the records as shown -

```
UPDATE_DATE             ORDER_ID    FIELD_NAME      OLD_FIELD_VAL      NEW_FIELD_VALUE
17-07-20                300009086   Order Stage     Provisioned         Shipped    
15-07-20                300009086   Order Stage     Order Created       Provisioned
14-07-20                300009086   Order Stage        -                Order Created 
14-07-20                300009086   Customer Name      -                XYZ Corp
```

So target table contains 2 different columns, OLD and NEW values, and we need to transpose the current and the immediate previous value records from source into one row in the target table so that it is easier to do reporting on this data.

So wanted to get some suggestions as what would be the best way to write a SQL to do this transpose. Would be grateful if someone can give some idea on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()`:

```
select
    update_date,
    order_id,
    field_name,
    lag(field_value) 
        over(partition by order_id, field_name order by update_date) as old_field_value
    field_value as new_field_value
from mytable
```